# How to get the sender of the first message in a thread

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

Let's assume I am selecting several messages in MacMail and that each message consists of a thread of messages between 3 different people (the initial sender, watson and me). How can I get in each iteration the "initial sender"?

```
set myReply to "Override"

set theSender to "Me <me@gmail.com>"

tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to selection
    if theSelection is {} then return
    activate
    set myList to {}
    repeat with thisMessage in theSelection
        if (extract address from sender of thisMessage) is "watson@gmail.com" then
            set theOutgoingMessage to reply thisMessage with properties {visible:true, sender:theSender}
            delay 1
            tell application "System Events"
                keystroke myReply
                delay 1
            end tell
            send theOutgoingMessage
            delay 1
            set myList to myList
            delay 1
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

So basically this watson always replies within each conversation. I want to tell to Watson "override", but I want to send a confirmation email, like "tokens sent", to the actual first sender (initiator of the conversation) and not to watson.

Comment: I’m not proficient in AppleScript, however, I can tell you that this will operate on the selected message.  To get the original sender, you’ll need to examine the full headers of the entire thread if it’s still available.

Comment: Could you provide an example of such code? I'm also a beginner and I honestly have no idea how would I implement that

Comment: Before coding (to which I said I *wasn’t* proficient with), get the message headers and see if you can manually find the info you’re looking for. If you can’t no code will be able to  get it

Comment: What do you mean by message headers? the subject of the message?

Comment: [Email Header Tutorial](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/email-headers/)

Comment: Also, have you tried reading the answer at the bottom of the page? (https://www.macscripter.net/t/how-to-get-the-sender-of-the-first-message-in-a-thread/74489 - where you found the script)